# JavaFX FadeTransition.onSetOnFinished with CountdownLatch does not work as expected

Tags: animation, concurrency, javafx

I'm staring at my code and I'm pretty stuck with one issue:
I want to make a fade out transition, and i want to block current thread, while the fade transition is running.
So, my attempt was to create a CountDownLatch, which blocks the thread, until the transition.setOnFinished() is called, where I make a latch.countdown(). In short: i want to make sure, that the transition is always visible in full length.

Seemed pretty straight forward to me, but...
The setOnFinished() doesn't get called, BECAUSE the current thread mentioned above is blocked by the countdown latch.

How can i solve this issue? Thx in advance.

```
 private void initView() {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
        rect.heightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
        rect.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        rect.setOpacity(0.8f);

        getChildren().add(rect);

        MyUiAnimation animator = new MyUiAnimation();
        fadeInTransition = animator.getShortFadeInFor(this);

        fadeOutTransition = animator.getShortFadeOutFor(this);
        fadeOutTransition.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        latch.countDown();
                        setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

public void hide() {
        fadeInTransition.stop();

        if (isVisible()) {
            latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            fadeOutTransition.playFromStart();
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only modify and query the active scene graph on the JavaFX application thread.  All of your code works with the scene graph, so it all must be run on the JavaFX application thread.  If everything is already running on the JavaFX application thread, there is no reason for concurrency related constructs in your code.

If you use blocking calls like `latch.await()`, you will block the JavaFX application thread, which will prevent any rendering, layout or animation steps to run.  `CountdownLatch` should not be used in this context and should be removed from the code.

Calling `Platform.runLater` is unnecessary as it's purpose is to run code on the JavaFX application thread, and you are on the JavaFX application thread already.  `Platform.runLater` should not be used in this context and should be removed from the code.